# WPF Window Handle for Message Loop Only

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

I am writing a WPF application that will put an icon in the system tray and, as an exercise, I want to do this without depending on `System.Windows.Forms` and using its `NotifyIcon` or `NativeWindow` classes.

This is fairly easy - `Shell_NotifyIcon` isn't hard to call from C# - and, indeed, I have succeeded in my task.

As part of this effort, I have had to create a window handle for the sole purpose of receiving messages from the system-tray. I create the native window as follows:

```
// Create a 'Native' window
_hwndSource = new HwndSource(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, parentHandle);
_hwndSource.AddHook(WndProc);
```

The message loop is hooked in `AddHook()` and messages are processed in a function that looks like this:

```
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    // Handle windows messages in this...
}
```

And, finally, when it comes time to destroy the thing, I close the window by posting it a `WM_CLOSE` message and disposing the `HwndSource`.

```
if (null != _hwndSource)
{
    UnsafeNativeMethods.PostMessage(_hwndSource.Handle, WindowMessage.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    _hwndSource.Dispose();
    _hwndSource = null;
}
```

My question is this: **the first three parameters to the constructor of `HwndSource` are the class style, style and extended style of the native Win32 window, respectively. For a non-visible window that will only be used as a target for window-messages, what should they be?**

My defaults of zero, zero and ... er.. zero do work but I have used Spy++ to examine what `Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` does and it seems that the `NativeWindow` it creates have the following:

```
Class Style:     <zero>
Styles:          WS_CAPTION, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
                 WS_OVERLAPPED
Extended Styles: WS_EX_LEFT, WS_EX_LTRREADING,
                 WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR, WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE
```

Are any of those important for a non-visible window? (I think not.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows style flags date from 1986, back when Windows v1.0 was released.  There have been *lots* of appcompat hacks in the past 29 years and 10 major versions, Windows silently overrides style flags when the app specifies wonky ones.  Nothing terribly wonky about this however, note that the value of the `WS_OVERLAPPED` style flag is 0.  Which asks for a plain window, you automatically get the appropriate style flags for such a window.

Your `HwndSource` window has the exact same style flags, maybe you haven't found the correct one back in Spy++.  So you don't have a problem.  And no, they don't matter when the window never becomes visible.

Note a bug in your code, the `WM_CLOSE` message you post is never actually processed since you destroy the window right after calling `PostMessage()`.  Just delete it, there is no point in asking the window nicely, it isn't going to object.  You do however have to call `Shell_NotifyIcon()` with `NIM_DELETE` to delete the tray icon.  Failure to do so leaves a "ghost" icon that only disappears when you move the mouse over it.

And do note that `NotifyIcon` is not as trivial as you assume it is, it has a [non-obvious bug workaround](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NotifyIcon.cs,fc0e2a272ada0b8f) that you are likely to overlook.  You'll notice when the context menu refuses to close.

Comment: In native Windows API programming, you'd use a [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only) in this scenario. Can this be used with a [HwndSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.aspx) as well? The [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Interop/HwndSource.cs,ee020061aa75cef1) wasn't terribly enlightening to me.

Comment: Yes, HwndSource does not object.  Use `new IntPtr(-3)` instead of *parentHandle*

Comment: Thanks, all. Those are exactly the facts that I required. I had forgotten about HWND_MESSAGE - that's probably more correct for the parent hwnd. I did, in fact, know about the "non-obvious bug workaround" but thanks, anyway - I am certain it will be helpful to other readers of this question, as will the info about NIM_DELETE which was already part of my code but I didn't consider it relevant to the question. Also, if you say I don't need to post WM_CLOSE because I'm disposing the HwndSource, I'll take that (the post-message) out. (WinForms' NativeWindow posts WM_CLOSE, for the record.)

Comment: It seems that you can't practically use a message-only window for the message-loop behind task-tray icons. Firstly, one of the primary responsibilities of that message loop is to catch Explorer's `TaskbarCreated` message which is only sent to top-level windows. Secondly, the aforementioned non-obvious bug workaround requires the window to become the foreground window before displaying a context menu. Children of `HWND_MESSAGE` are never top-level and can't be the foreground window, at least according to my rusty Win32 knowledge.